# Flutter FilterChip Avatar Selected Style

Tags: flutter, material-design, material-ui

I'm using `FilterChip` with a `CircleAvatar` for avatar, but the selected state has a nasty rectangle that I can't seem to find any reference for. How do I remove it?

Code:

```
child: FilterChip(
        avatar: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: category.color
        ),
        label: Text(category.name),
        selected: badCategoryIds.contains(category.id),
        onSelected: (bool value) {
          if (value) {
            badCategoryIds.add(category.id);
          }
          else {
            badCategoryIds.remove(category.id);
          }
          categoryChoiceCallback(badCategoryIds);
        },
      )
```

Result:

[image]

How I want it to appear (taken from [material.io](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#filter-chips) documentation):

[image]

[FilterChip documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FilterChip-class.html).

Comment: I think this is a bug, check out this issue
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24773

Comment: @dlohani Oh thanks. Wonder if there's a workaround

Answer (score 2):

You can try to adapt this solution for a Circle Image for your Chip Circle as well

```
new Container(
  width: 190.0,
  height: 190.0,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      image: new DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: new NetworkImage(
             "https://i.imgur.com/BoN9kdC.png")
             )
)),
```

from this Medium Post https://medium.com/@boldijar.paul/circle-image-view-in-flutter-965963c46cf5